# Disable Ctrl+P (Print) on WebBrowser control

Tags: delphi, printing, browser

i use webbrowser in my delphi application . how can i disable Ctrl+P to prevent print ?

Comment: You could intercept the keypress in the host form, but that just wouldn't be enough to prevent printing...
You would also need to intercept Ctrl+C (copy), selection in the browser window (which could be copied too), and you would also have to prevent printing via screen capture (which can be accomplished by merely hitting the "Print Screen" key, even with the focus in another application, and pasting the result in Word or WordPad).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the code below :

```
var
 mClass : Array[0..1024] of Char;
begin
 if (GetClassName(Msg.hwnd, mClass, 1024) > 0) then
  begin
   if (StrIComp(@mClass, 'Internet Explorer_Server') = 0) then
    begin
     if Msg.message = WM_KEYDOWN then
      Handled := (Msg.wParam = Ord('P')) and (GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) <> 0);
    end
  end;
end;
```

To prevent messages sent to a TWebBrowser control , we can get the class name of message receiver and then compare the class name with "Internet Explorer_Server" that is the IE Server Calss Name , if class-names where equal then you can make sure that the message sent to WebBrowser Control , now you can Handle Message arrived ...
In the code above we do this to Handle Ctrl+P Shortcut , but you can use this idea for more like disabling Context Menu or ...
Notice that when a page loaded in the WebBrowser , messages will post to IE Server not to TWebBrowser Handle ...

First Put a TApplicationEvents on the Form , next Copy/Paste code from here to it`s OnMessage Event ...

Good Luck ...

Comment: This didn't work for me.  When I examine the messages, I see the class name as 'Shell Embedding', not 'Internet Explorer_Server'.  Perhaps something has changed since this was posted in 2010.

Answer (score 0):

I used EmbeddedWB and my problem solved via this tiny code :

```
procedure TForm1.EmbeddedWb1KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; ScanCode: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  Key := 0;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but I wanted to update with the method I found to work.  This builds on the helpful post by @Mahmood_N.

Notice that I first wrote the code to get the class name, and compared that to 'Shell Embedding', which is what showed up for TWebBrowser messages (see here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/244310).  But my application will include more than one TWebBrowser, so I modified it to be better, by getting the window handle directly, and use that for comparison with the handle of the window message.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, AppEvnts, StdCtrls, OleCtrls, SHDocVw, ActiveX;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    WebBrowser: TWebBrowser;
    ApplicationEvents1: TApplicationEvents;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ApplicationEvents1Message(var Msg: tagMSG; var Handled: Boolean);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    WBHandle : THandle;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function GetStrClassName(Handle: THandle): String;
var
  Buffer: array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
begin
  Windows.GetClassName(Handle, @Buffer, MAX_PATH);
  Result := String(Buffer);
end;

procedure TForm1.ApplicationEvents1Message(var Msg: tagMSG; var Handled: Boolean);
var
  ClassName : string;
begin
  ClassName := GetStrClassName(Msg.hwnd);
  //if Pos('Shell Embedding', ClassName) > 0 then begin
  if Msg.hwnd = WBHandle then begin
    if Msg.message = WM_KEYDOWN then begin
      Handled := (Msg.wParam = Ord('P')) and (GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) <> 0);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var Win : IOLEWindow;
    WinHandle : HWND;
begin
  WBHandle := 0;
  if WebBrowser.ControlInterface.QueryInterface(IOleWindow, Win) = 0 then begin
    if Win.GetWindow(WinHandle) = 0 then begin
      WBHandle := WinHandle;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: WebBrowser.Handle gives the exact same handle as your implementation (FormCreate). Maybe this sollution is outdated also, because there are a property that returns the same value already. The Msg.Handle, in fact, is the handle of "Internet Explorer_Server"